# Email script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get an email sent to me when a form is submitted and the information populates a spreadsheet. It worked yesterday but since then all I'm getting is an error

> 7/13/14 5:23 PM   sendFormByEmail TypeError: Cannot call method
>   "toString" of undefined. (line 20, file "Email Script")   formSubmit

[image]

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address
  var email = "lumbyb@gmatc.matc.edu"; 

  // Optional but change the following variable
  // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
  var subject = "PC Repair Ticket";  

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";    

  // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order

  for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 

  // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
  // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp here.

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  // Watch the following video for details
  // http://youtu.be/z6klwUxRwQI

  // By Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value exists before converting to a string.

```
  for(var i in headers) {
    if (e.namedValues[headers[i]]) {
      message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
    }
  }
```